# Xpath query help

Tags: xml, xpath

In Xpath how can I query if I'm looking for the **child's age and name whom has NO grandchild**

```
 <documentRoot>
 <parent name="data" >

  <child id="1"  name="alpha" >
   <anotherchild>
     <age>20</age>
     <grandchild/>
   </anotherchild>
  </child>

  <child id="2"  name="beta" >
   <anotherchild>
     <age>50</age>
     <grandchild id="2.1"  name="beta-alpha" ></grandchild>
     <grandchild id="2.2"  name="beta-beta" ></grandchild>
   </anotherchild>
  </child>

 </parent>
</documentRoot>
```

Comment: The first `<child>` element contains invalid markup. There is a `</grandchild>` with no corresponding `<grandchild>`.

Comment: I don't understand your question. Both your `<child>` elements have a `<grandchild>` element in their content (which also, confusingly, happens to be a grandchild of the child element in the XPath tree model). Which of these child elements are you trying to select?

Comment: I asked "who has no grandchild" but not "who has no grandchild element" Tnx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like your XML has some typos. Assuming your XML is like this (with `<grandchild/>` instead of `</grandchild>` under the first `<child>` and a closing `</documentRoot>`

```
<documentRoot>
    <parent name="data">
        <child id="1" name="alpha">
            <age>20</age>
            <grandchild/>
        </child>
        <child id="2" name="beta">
            <age>50</age>
            <grandchild id="2.1" name="beta-alpha"/>
            <grandchild id="2.2" name="beta-beta"/>
        </child>
    </parent>
</documentRoot>
```

This XPath will select the age of child element where `<grandchild/>` exists without an `@id`

```
//child[not(anotherchild/grandchild/@id)]/anotherchild/age
```

this will return the name for the same `child`

```
//child[not(anotherchild/grandchild/@id)]/anotherchild/@name
```

Comment: tnx I updated my xml can you have a look again? also why didnt you use something like (not(contains(grandchild, '*'))) can you explain?

Comment: @XDeveloper - I updated to include `anotherchild` - you still need to close `<documentRoot>` correctly. `not(anotherchild/grandchild/@id)` evaluates to false for the first `child` because no node with the path `anotherchild/grandchild/@id` exists. `contains(grandchild, '*')` checks if there is a grandchild element that has text with some value. In this case both child nodes nave `grandchild`, the only difference is the attributes are not there.